# First Icon On Desktop Always Selected

Tags: keyboard

My laptop is running Windows 10 and is in a state in which the first icon on the desktop is always selected. We can not select any other icon or open any other programs from desktop. It is also in the case of a web page.

Also we can not drag down to the bottom of the web page. On the keyboard the num lock key is always on and it is not working. Also no other keys and the touch pad are not working. I tried with a external mouse and keyboard and it is working fine. How can I tackle this ?

I have created a new user profile and key board and touch pad is working. And icon selection also not there but when we press the NumLock key then all the things back to  old condition. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

> *On the keyboard the num lock key is always on and it is not working. Also no other keys and the touch pad are not working. I tried with a external mouse and keyboard and it is working fine.*

Your laptop keyboard/touchpad is the issue and is probably defective. If the problem were *only* with the keyboard and not the touchpad, I'd be inclined to suggest cleaning the keyboard and making sure none of the keys are stuck. However, based on your report that:

- The touchpad is also non-functional, and
- External keyboard and mouse work

It's obvious the built-in keyboard and touchpad is the problem. You can try re-seating the cable(s) connecting it to the laptop's motherboard (use a service manual to determine how to do this). If that fails, you should replace the entire component.

Comment: Thank for your rply i will try the reset and update

Comment: I have tried creating another user account and it allows to work key board and touch pad well. But the thing is that when you press NumLock then that profile also went like another one first icon selected key board and touch pad not working can any body explain this

Comment: Please update your question with this information. It considerably changes things.